# Trying to Create New Reporting Snapshot - But, Custom Object is not available in the List of Target Object to select from

Tags: reporting, snapshot

Trying to Create New Reporting Snapshot - But, Custom Object is not available in the List of Target Object to select from.

We have Accounts as a Master-Detail on that object. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Target object must not be a detail object in a master-detail relationship in the reporting snapshot.

> The custom object in the Target Object field is a detail object in a
> master-detail relationship, meaning that a master object controls
> certain behaviors on the target object's records. Choose a target
> object that is not included in a master-detail relationship.

Refer the [Troubleshoot Reporting Snapshots](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_troubleshooting_snapshots.htm&type=5)